# How to compare a parameter of a Stored procedure with a REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-regexp

I have a stored Procedure that I want to use for validations in the tables, and I have a regexp that I need to compare one of the parameters, how can I compare the regexp with my parameter. I tried this:

`SELECT id REGEXP '^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$'`

id is the parameter that I receive, this is all the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER &&  
CREATE PROCEDURE ValidationSalaryChange(
    IN changeDate DATE,
    IN id VARCHAR(11)
))  
BEGIN  
    IF NOT (SELECT id REGEXP '^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$') THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'error';
    ELSE IF (changeDate > NOW()) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'error'; 
    END IF;
END &&  
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You don't need the subquery. Just `IF id NOT REGEXP '...'`

Comment: But I think your way should work as well. What problem are you having?

Comment: @Barmar Hi, how would you do it?, and its giving me error: 1064  in this line: `IF NOT (SELECT id REGEXP ('^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$')`

Comment: You have an extra `(` after `REGEXP`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the subquery.

You have an extra `)` after the parameter list.

`ELSE IF` needs to be one word `ELSEIF`.

```
DELIMITER &&  
CREATE PROCEDURE ValidationSalaryChange(
    IN changeDate DATE,
    IN id VARCHAR(11)
)
BEGIN  
    IF id NOT REGEXP '^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'error in id';
    ELSEIF changeDate > NOW() THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'error in changeDate'; 
    END IF;
END &&  
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried this but keeps sending the same error (1064) in the same line

Comment: `ELSE IF` needs to be `ELSEIF`. I tested this, it doesn't get a syntax error.

Comment: Note that you can only use `\d` in regexp in MySQL 8.x. In older versions use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: This is my version: 10.5.7-MariaDB-1:10.5.7+maria~focal, this may be why this does work for you but no for me?

Comment: MariaDB started using PCRE in 10.0.5 so you should be able to use `\d`. I don't see anything else that would be version-dependent.